# Excel VBA Copying sheet from closed workbook to current workbook, but copies outdated sheet

Tags: excel, vba, copy

I am on Excel 2003 should that make a difference.

I have a small function that opens a file by path, copies over its first (and only) sheet to the current workbook. Closes the opened template and renames the newly created sheet.

The thing is when it does this the new sheet that is made is and older version of the template file?

The file is located at "E:\Cascade\RunSheet-Heath Edition\CH54\CH54_Template.xlt"

```
Sub LoadTemplate2()
    'disables the refreshing of the screen to speed up the script
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    
    directory = "E:\Cascade\RunSheet-Heath Edition\CH54\"
    templateName = "CH54_Template"
    fileExt = ".xlt"
    bookName = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    Debug.Print (bookName)
    filePath = directory & templateName & fileExt
    Dim wb As Workbook
    
    'opens the template
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(filePath)
    
    'copy over the template sheet 
    Sheets(1).Copy _
    Before:=Workbooks(bookName).Worksheets(1)
    
    'closes the template
    wb.Close

    ' renames the newly created sheet
    Sheets(1).Name = "RunSheet"

    'Resume updating the screen
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

I am about to try to select a range and try copying that over, but seems odd that this is happening anyway.

It seems like a weird cache thing to me. as if the Front end excel interface shows the true data but for whatever reason the VBA script pulls from an older version of the template file.

I have saved both workbooks and closed them, even restarted the computer, the template is as it should be. Not what it is currently pasting. What it is pasting is not even saved on the computer as a file anymore, nor is it opened when I go line by line step through in the code. The correct file is being opened.

I should note that when I open up the template but just clicking the file on Windows the excel header is CH54_Template1.xlt, and not just "CH54_Template.xlt" as the file is named.

[I start with one workbook open:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lhu5Y.png)
I run the code which opens:
[this file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zk7c8.png)
[The code finished and I am left with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsRvE.png)
which is from something I had made a month or so ago and since deleted.

Comment: Are you sure your xlt template file doesn't contain a hidden/very hidden sheet in the first position?  What you see when you open the template might not be the sheet that gets copied over.

Comment: This was it! on my older version of excel i could not simple right click the open tabs and select hide or unhide. I had to right click the arrows to the left of my open tabs to get it to work.

Cheers!